# Is tinfoil possible to prevent missile tracking radar?

Tags: realism, the-bourne-legacy

In the beginning of [*The Bourne Legacy* (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1194173/), Aaron Cross was in training in Alaska, and met with another agent. There's a scene when Aaron ran out of the cabin, and the missile destroyed the cabin. He immediately put some tinfoil (can't see clearly, I guess so) close fitted to his body, and then the drone is no longer able to track him. In reality, would this actually work?

[image]

Comment: This concept is the basis for the phrase, "[Tinfoil Hat Conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil_hat)".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question.. it's tagged with realism and it can be provided a decently credible answer. Much more obscure questions regarding realism have been answered before.

Comment: About 20 minutes later in the film we see him pull a tracking sensor out of his leg, specifically in the exact location that he initially covered himself with the tinfoil and aluminum plate. So..

Comment: @Charles - It dances the line between Trivia and Realism.  Although, you could effectively argue that any question with the Realism tag does the exact same.  I think it's a fair question, and I agree with you that it should stay.

Comment: *the drone is no longer able to track him*... yeah, no. Not unless all you're trying to use is a map like those idiots. - "[The aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-1_Predator#Command_and_sensor_systems) is equipped with the AN/AAS-52 Multi-spectral Targeting System, a color nose camera (generally used by the pilot for flight control), a variable aperture day-TV camera, and a variable aperture thermographic camera (for low light/night)." - The Taliban didn't have trackers in their legs; they were white dots on a black background. No more white dots? Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 5):

The "tinfoil" appears to be a folded thermal blanket and this is further covered by a tin plate of some kind.

Whether this would be thick enough to actually form a sort of [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage#:%7E:text=A%20Faraday%20cage%20or%20Faraday,who%20invented%20them%20in%201836.) is open to debate but the principle is there.

It's unlikely the tracker implanted is *that* strong so, arguably, for movie purposes, the answer to your question is "Yes".